# Kerberos using JAAS and SMB protocol

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas, smb

We are using JAAS for Kerberos authentication. As a requirement from the customer, we want to make sure that SMB V2 or higher must be used during communication with KDC/AD.

I've few basic questions related to this. Please excuse me if I sound too naive.

1. Does SMB protocol come really into picture while using Kerberos authentication and credential delegation (esp with JAAS)?
2. If yes, then is there any way we can identify which SMB version is being used? For eg- may be monitoring network traffic?
3. Best practice to implement Kerberos + SMB? Any thoughts on latest JCIFS (available on GIT) libraries?

Any pointers are highly appreciated ! Thanks,
Bhushan

Comment: The way I see it, SMB is *for* exchanging file and print information, and it is capable of *using* Krb as a means of mutually authenticating the parties in such an exchange.  See section '1.4 - Relationship to other protocols' in the [SMB 2 and 3 spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/5606ad47-5ee0-437a-817e-70c366052962).

Comment: In the SMB 2/3 spec, section 1.4, we read: `For authentication, the SMB 2 Protocol relies on Simple and Protected GSS-API Negotiation (SPNEGO),
as described in [MS-AUTHSOD] section 2.1.2.3.1 and specified in [RFC4178] and [MS-SPNG], which in turn can rely on the Kerberos Protocol Extensions (as specified in [MS-KILE]) or the NT LAN Manager (NTLM) Authentication Protocol (as specified in [MS-NLMP]).` Your customer is probably wanting to assert that NTLMv2 or higher is being used, but can't distinguish between SMBv2 and NTLMv2.  SMB does not enter your equation.

Comment: Yeah, SMB has no bearing whatsoever on how Kerberos functions. Kerberos is an optional dependency of SMB, not the other way around. Delegation is either built in to Kerberos itself or through an extension called [MS-SFU] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sfu/3bff5864-8135-400e-bdd9-33b552051d94

Comment: Thanks @DavidBullock and Steve for the inputs. We are currently using JCIFS (old version) in our product solely for the Kerberos authentication. There is no file or other resource access is involved. One of our customers reported that JCIFS is using SMB 1 for some reasons. I am not sure how do I deal with this.

Comment: The https://www.jcifs.org/ home page says "SMBv1 only".  So if your app wants to do the sorts of things SMB is used for (which I guess it does if you use JCIFS), then you're in the market for a new library.  However, at no time will mere Kerberos authentication send an SMB packet to the KDC/AD ... unless it is exchanging a file or print stream with the domain controller ... which would be a bizzare thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBullock. Yes we tested Kerberos authentication by disabling SMB1 on both DC and application server. It is working fine. This proves SMB doesnt come into picture during Kerberos auth.